# document.getElementByTagName is not a function

Tags: javascript

The code supposed to be use javascript between the `<script>` tags that
consists of a mouseover event, and the list items in the HTML page must
be styled as follows: normal - black, 12, bold and over yellow, 15, bold, italic.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Using mouseover eve </title>
<script language = "javascript">
<!--
    function changeStyle() {

        var item = document.getElementByTagName("li");
        item.style.color = "yellow";
        item.style.fontSize = "15pt";
            item.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        item.style.fontStyle = "italic";

    }
-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul style = "color: black; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold" >
    <li onMouseOver = "changeStyle()"> item 1 </li>
    <li onMouseOver = "changeStyle()"> item 2 </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 20):

That's because the correct function name is **`getElementsByTagName`** and **not** `getElementByTagName`.

```
 var items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
```

This will return a Nodelist of elements with that particular tag name (in this case, all list items in the document).

Then, you could target your li's specifically as you wish, for example:

```
items[0].style.color = "yellow"; // first li is yellow when mouseover
items[1].style.color = "red"; // second li is red when mouseover
```

etc.

Comment: The problem is, `item` is now a `NodeList`, and should be renamed to `items`.

Comment: @JanDvorak thanks for that, i am still new at this and i am learning.

Answer (score 4):

The correct name for the function is `getElementsByTagName` (with an 's') and it returns an array of elements, not just a single one. If you want to get the first item from the array you will need to do somethig like this:

```
var item = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[0];
```

Comment: that was a silly mistake of me leaving out the 's', now it works but it only works on the first item when i over it, and now m strugling to get it work on other items in the list.

Answer (score 1):

it should be document.getElement**s**ByTagName